# How to properly handle multiple Runtime errors?

Tags: python

**Program description:**

> Program accepts a file name and a segment, consisting of two numbers (each divided by one space). Then it outputs all lines from existing file where their indicies lie within the given segment.

**My solution:**

```
import sys
try:
    par = input("Input (<file> <low border of the segment> <high border of the segment>): ").split(' ')
    print(17 * '-')
    f = par[0]
    f_lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in f if line != "\n"]
    length = len(f_lines)
    if (par == ''):
        raise RuntimeError('Error: undefined')
    if (par[2] == None) or (par[2] == ''):
        raise RuntimeError('Error: segment is limited')
    if ((par[1] and par[2]) == None) or ((par[1] and par[2]) == ''):
        raise RuntimeError('Error: segment undefined')
    if (int(par[2]) >= length):
        raise RuntimeError('Error: segment can not be greater than length the amount of lines')
    if (par[1] == ''):
        a = 0
    if (par[2] == ''):
        b = 0
    segment = [int(par[1]), (int(par[2]) + 1)]
    with open(par[0]) as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
        for k in range(segment[0], segment[1]):
            print(data[k])
except (FileNotFoundError, IOError, NameError):
    print('[!] Error: your input is incorrect. The file may be missing or something else. \n[?] For further information see full error logs: \n',sys.exc_info())
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

**Problem:**

> When I try running my program in different ways to test each of my Runtime errors I always get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\IT\pycharm\sem_2.py", line 10, in <module>
    if (par[2] == None) or (par[2] == ''):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

> I cannot wrap my head around how can I properly handle multiple Runtime errors so they would display as a text message. I haven't found any solution to my question anywhere online, so I'm trying to ask here.

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to catch ***all other*** exceptions than `(FileNotFoundError, IOError, NameError)`? Are you looking for a simple `except Exception`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, this is what I was trying to do actually - handle all Runtime erros and output a unique message to each of them

Comment: @JoshJohnson why are you not catching `IndexError`?

Comment: @RandomDavis I wanted to do custom error messages.

Comment: Well if you want a specific message to each possible exception you will have to catch all of them which is not very efficient... But you usually know what exceptions your program throws. So, why not just catch `IndexError`? Your problem is that `IndexError is not RuntimeError` as can be seen in the [Exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy). It is, though a `LookupError`

Comment: Ok, @Tomerikoo, thanks for your help, will do as you've suggested!

Comment: By the way, this `f_lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in f if line != "\n"]` doesn't do what you think it does. Because `f = par[0]` is just a string... I think you meant `f = open(par[0])`

Comment: Oh this I have missed as well, thank you so much! :)

Comment: No problem. Lastly, a piece of advice. The `try/except` block is mostly intended to be used on the ***least*** amount of code possible - exactly the lines you think will raise an error. You are wrapping your ***whole code*** with it. So for example your `IndexError` could be otherwise more generally handled by doing `if len(par) != 3: print("Error!")`. The `FileNotFoundError` should be wrapping the `with` statement. And lastly, there is no reason to catch a `NameError`. If there is a `NameError`, your code will not run, it is not related to user input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would catch `FileNotFoundError`, `IOError`, `NameError` and `RuntimeError` but what is actually thrown is `IndexError` and that is not handled.

You may want to add `IndexError` it to the first `except` block:

```py
except (FileNotFoundError, IOError, NameError, IndexError):
    print('[!] Error: input incorrect!')   # ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or perhaps add another `except` block if you want a custom message for `IndexError`:

```py
except (FileNotFoundError, IOError, NameError):
    print('[!] Error: input incorrect!')
except IndexError:
    print('[!] Error: IndexError just happened!')
```

---

By the way, the following will always be `False` because the code in parentheses will resolve to a `bool` first, which can either be `True` or `False` and these are obviously never equal to `''` or `None`:

```py
((par[1] and par[2]) == None) or ((par[1] and par[2]) == '')
```

You may way want to rewrite it to:

```py
(par[1] is None and par[2] is None) or (par[1] == '' and par[2] == '')
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about outputting a unique message for each of my Runtime errors? This was actually my initial idea :)

Comment: Right now you're getting an `IndexError` that is thrown in one of the `if`s. Once you get rid of it, I suppose you should start getting proper `RuntimeError`s with message depending on which case was hit.

Comment: But the `IndexError` is a possible one... If the user doesn't pass all arguments it will be an `IndexError`...

Comment: Hmm that's true. In this case if we want a custom message for it, we could add another `except` block to catch just `IndexError`. I have added that option to the answer.